# way to customize face colors with the overlay face orientation

Tags: modeling

In the > 2.8 version of blender, we have the face orientation overlay feature that colors front facing normaled faces with blue and back facing ones to red like so:
[image]

This is very useful, but also somewhat distracting at times. Is there a setting that lets us customize this color? Because sometimes I just find it more useful and wish there a material dark color because these flat colors sometimes are to much flat it's hard to distinguish and view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can change it in the preferences in *"themes"* part for the 3d viewport:

[image]